# how to show child ul under parent ul horizontally

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

i asked several times for my navigation here but didn't get my desire results so i thought one last time maybe someone help me to achieve like this!

[image: the telegraph site]

as you can see in below code i have only 5 parent menus and each of them have at least 12 child or submenus. i want to show my 5 parent or main menus horizontally like as you can see above image where `home` `video` `news` `world` `sport` etc and display their related child menus right under of it also horizontally again you look at image and notice parent link `news` selected and their child links like `politics` `investigations` `obits` `education` etc shown below him horizontally. and also notice that parent link `news` and child link `investigations` both have active class at the same time and i also want this effect.

and if you please visit this [link - the telegraph](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/investigations/) you can also see if you refresh the page both navigation's remain intact and also maintains their active state.

this is my attempt please check out this [fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/aqeelpld/bqubq4rf/2/) in this fiddle you notice that when page is refreshed child navigation disappears and also problem with active link state only one link remains active but as you now know i want parent link to remain active even when i am on any of his child links just like you seen on `the telegraph` site in above link.

**notes**

- i used jquery ajax to load pages dynamically to a div and also used hash in my urls.
- also used this [jquery bbq](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/) `html5 history api` based jquery ajax plugin to load pages, browser history and browser back and forward buttons and everything working fine.

please feel free to use any jquery lib any hack or what ever you like but i need this badly. anyone who can help me to achieve this i really appreciate him with bottom of my heart and also mention him on credits section of my site. thanks

**p.s:** ask any time for any further details if needed.

Comment: Please don't repeat questions because you didn't get answers to previous ones. You should either improve the previous questions to prompt answers **OR** delete them since they are no longer relevant.

Comment: The Telegraph is simply using the URL (and for a good reason) to figure out what tab you should be on. Achieving what you want would simply be reading the url (`window.location.pathname`) and using it to set some classes with JQuery.

Comment: This task you are asking help for require much more than a simple answer. You need to determine which method you will take to handle navigation information (cookies ? session ? url string query ? ...). Because of this reasons your question cannot be simply answered and don't fit the good way for asking question here. As always, my advice  is to separate your problem in little part, trying to move step by step to indentify which part of the problem is getting rude and coming back here to explain with a well produced example what you expected and your actual result.

Comment: The telegraph site can easily retain the correct navigation on refresh as the page dictates what is active. for example you gave a link to `news/investigations/` which will always have news and investigations active. 
 you need to give a lot more information about the setup of your website for us to be able to give you any real constructive advice

Comment: @Zeratops  i don't agree any one of these comments. its a simple question and i already did most of the part if any one of you read my question carefully then must know i mentioned couple of times for my problem and also provide fiddle if you seen fiddle then you better understand what i am asking for! but i know you guys just read post title and see picture and then you thought of commenting and i challenge you!

Comment: @arcade I checked your JSFiddle, I commented your question because knowing your result, your question really looks like _I made this, I want this, how to do ?_, plus the fact you are not aiming your question on one issue but several ones which make the whole question confusing.

Comment: @bruceyyy please tell me what kind of information you need about my site i will glad to provide you with any information.

Comment: @Zeratops i don't think so! maybe because you didn't understood my question right or whatever the reason but if you look at my question i clearly said that i attempt that fiddle and did most of it except when page is refreshed child navigation disappears and active state gone! and all other words, picture and links i post because i tried to explain what i want! i am not just post pictures and links and said.....hey folks plz watch these things i want them but also provide my efforts and just asked what problem i have and i think that's why `stackoverflow` is exists. thanks